# Get WEB_URL from file

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, url

I have a problem with my android app. I want to get WEB_URL from text file which contains only site URL. How can I do that? I dont have an exact site URL. i wanna change my site URL remotely, the text file i put to free hosting and if i change my web site api, it should not affect to my program
My code:

```
package com.app.notch.connection;

import com.my.app.BuildConfig;
import com.my.app.data.Constant;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RestAdapter {

    public static API createAPI() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            builder.addInterceptor(logging);
        }
        builder.cache(null);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constant.WEB_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(API.class);
    }

}
```

```
package com.gogosh.me;

public class Constant {


    public static String WEB_URL = "example.com";

    public static final String SECURITY_CODE = "DfjxRkX1nTgeSz8DturkK25kWE1Sfe12wnyvqrlloS0zY5yj8mR8Ge3";

    public static String MORE_APP_URL = "http://example.com/more";

 

    public static int NEWS_PER_REQUEST = 10;
    public static int TOPIC_PER_REQUEST = 10...
```

i tried to use `readFile()`. but it's not working

EDITED:
my english is not clear, thats way its little hard to describe, but i'm trying. i tried to solve this problem with making 301 redirect to other site which located api from my free domain, but it's not working. thats way i want to make txt file which contains my main site url and my program can read from it .i could change my main site domain, and it shoudnt affect to my programm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307620/can-i-get-string-from-text-file

Comment: Pretty strange that you keep repeating closed questions with the same text. You could rephrase it as now its unclear. You have two accounts?

Comment: my english is not clear, thats way its little hard to describe, but i'm trying. i tried to solve this problem with making 301 redirect to other site which located api from my free domain, but it's not working. thats way i want to make txt file which contains my main site url and my program can read from it .i could change my main site domain, and it shoudnt affect to my programm. now clear?

Comment: And where is that text file stored?

Comment: in free hosting with domain

Comment: Downloading a file is a pretty standard action so why would that be a problem? You can find a hundred examples on the internet and here on stackoverflow.

Comment: ive tried many of them. but all of them not working. maybe i cant put to right place, maybe its not compatible.

Comment: can you help me to solve this problem?